# How to fetch data from persistent store and show on the customized table viewcell? Is there any sample code?

Tags: objective-c, icloud

Tim roadley has similar answers but dint picture a mere of my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple made amazing [tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305). In this sample you can know how to use Core Data with `UITableView`. Once I used it like introduction in Core Data.
Hope it was helpful.